# Syntastic close error window and original file window

Tags: vim, syntastic

I've installed Syntastic from GitHub and I'm trying to use Syntastic for checking perl syntax errors (and planning to use for Python in a short while). When I use ':quit' or ':q', only original file window closes. The error window does not close. Below is snip from my .vimrc file :

```
execute pathogen#infect()  
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#  
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}  
set statusline+=%*  
let g:syntastic_perl_checkers = ['perl']  
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint']  
let g:syntastic_enable_perl_checker = 1  
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1  
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1  
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
```

Since I'm very new to vim scripting, I would like to know how to close both windows, error window and original file window, when I use ':quit' or ':q' while original file window is active.

Comment: `:q` closes the current window, not Vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the normal Vim behavior; it has nothing to do with Syntastic. The *quickfix* or *location list* windows may contain references to other files, so it is not certain that you want to completely leave Vim when quitting from the originating window.

The simplest solution is using `:qa` (quit all) instead of `:q`. As the error window doesn't contain unpersisted changes, this is safe and doesn't require a confirmation.

If you are annoyed by having to think about this, you can use Vim's scripting capabilities to change its behavior:

```
:autocmd WinEnter * if &buftype ==# 'quickfix' && winnr('$') == 1 | quit | endif
```

This checks on each change of window whether there's only one window left, and if that one is a quickfix / location list, it quits Vim.

Comment: Actually, `:q` in the main window __does__ close both windows, that's a feature of syntastic.  The same doesn't work in the error window because it isn't safe.  `:q` in the error window should still close the error window; the fact that it doesn't, is a bug. :) I'll commit a patch soon.

Comment: @lcd047 No..... the `:q` in the main window **does not** close both the windows. The error window still remains open. Also, `:q` in error window **does not** close anything. Both the windows remain open. Is the behavior dependent on specific vim version ?

Comment: @Nilesh Bhave: It's supposed to behave the way I described, depending on syntastic version, on interaction with other plugins, and on absence of bugs.  Sadly, the bug I mentioned above is not as easy to fix as I first thought.  If you have other problems to report, please do so at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).

Answer (score 4):

Try the below command:

`:lclose`

Answer (score 3):

According to [Syntastic help](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt), the command to close Syntastic error window is:

```
:SyntasticReset
```